# Open Link in GNOME Terminal under i3/sway not working

Tags: gnome-terminal, i3, sway

If I try to open a link in GNOME terminal, then nothing happens if I'm in a Sway/i3 session. If I try the same while running GNOME, then opening a link works, i.e., Firefox opens the link. Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: It works for me but [others have reported the same issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/issues/218). Try running `journalctl -f` before clicking a link.